Hashing pointers against the largest prime
In another forum someone asked for a hash-function to hash pointers. I suggested to multiply the pointer with the lagest prime fitting into an uintptr_t and ignore the overflow. Someone said that this would be a bad hash-function. So ran the numbers and looked how many collisions I get. The following code simulates this with a 32 bit unsigned integral which is multiplied with the largest prime fitting into 32 bit.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<uint8_t> buckets( 1ull << 32 );
    constexpr uint32_t P32 = 0xFFFFFFFBu;
    for( size_t b = buckets.size(); b; )
        if( !++buckets[(uint32_t)--b * P32 & (uint32_t)-1] )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    vector<size_t> loads;
    for( uint8_t ld : buckets )
    {
        if( loads.size() <= ld )
            loads.resize( ld + 1 );
        ++loads[ld];
    }
    for( size_t l = 0; ptrdiff_t ld : loads )
        cout << l++ << ": " << 100.0 * ld / 0x1p32 << "%" << endl;
}

To my surprise the code prints exactly size one buckets, i.e I get a perfect equal distribution and no collisions. Why is that ?
0: 0%
1: 100%


Someone with more expertise should write a full answer, but I imagine the problem with this scheme is that this hash function is easily reversible (it corresponds to multiplication by the prime modulo $2^{32}$, which one can undo by finding the modular inverse of that prime and multiplying by that inverse).

Basically, the questions is, how come for $\forall i\ne j, i,j\in\left{0,1,2,...,2^{32}\right} \Rightarrow i\cdot P32 \not\equiv j \cdot P32 \pmod{ 2^{32}}$, right?

If so, the answer is simple ... Assume $\exists i>j$ s.t.
$$i\cdot P32 \equiv j \cdot P32 \pmod{ 2^{32}} \Rightarrow\
2^{32} \mid P32 \cdot (i-j)$$
which is not possible because $P32$ is prime and $\gcd(P32, 2^{32})=1$ and $0<i-j<2^{32}$.

Well, $\mathrm{P32} \equiv -5 \pmod{2^{32}}$.  So $\mathrm{P32}^{-1} \equiv 858,993,459 \pmod{2^{32}}$.
